# How to add time axis both on top and down Timeline vis.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vis.js

Actually I want to create standard vis JS to show user timeline. I have more than 20 person data so the time axis on bottom timeline is hard to see when do zooming timeline. how to add time axis on both top and down timeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the orientation option and set "both" as value:

```
timeline.setOptions({orientation: {axis: "both"} });
```

Check this example: http://visjs.org/examples/timeline/styling/axisOrientation.html